# Powerapps how to choose fields that are submitted to SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have taken over a project from someone who has left the business.
It is a Microsoft PowerApp which provides users with a form interface to upload items into a SharePoint list.

The submit button in the app works and the function is "SubmitForm(formName)"

My question is how does it know which fields to submit into which column in SharePoint?

for instance if I wanted to create a textbox in the form for "First Name" how would I make the powerapp submit the contents of that textbox into firstname field?

--edit removed screenshot--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you lack knowledge of powerapps w.r.t sharepoint.
Go through one of the example mentioned in docs of micro soft and you will get idea of how mapping of fields are done.

Your main concern is mapping fields.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/app-from-sharepoint

If you check your edit form, and click on any of your field/data card you will find settings as below. Here I have created custom column as "NumberColumn" and you can find  Data properties same for your field as well.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I looked through the link but didn't see anything linked to mapping the fields.

Comment: I have the data connection set up and some of the fields that already existed work, I just dont know how to map the new fields I have added so that they submit to SP list

Comment: if you could add screenshot of your submit button form. by the way There are different types of form, edit, view and so on.

Comment: I've edited the original post with the screenshot. let me know if thats not the correct screenshot, thanks for your help is much appreciated

Comment: I have updated screenshot for one of my dummy sharepoint app.

Comment: Thank you, thats very helpful and I think i now have my head mostly around it.